# ghc-mod tries to execute cabal for a stack project (even though no dist/ dir is present)

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

I'm using ghc-mod installed using stack on OSX:

```
$ ghc-mod --version
ghc-mod version 5.4.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.10.3
```

However, when I try to use it in spacemacs or from the command line with a stack project which *does not* have a dist/ dir, it keeps trying to execute cabal.

```
$ ls
LICENSE     Setup.hs    app     foo.cabal   src     stack.yaml  test
$ ghc-mod check app/Main.hs
ghc-mod: cabal: readCreateProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Why is this?

Note I previously had the OSX ghc/cabal installation from https://ghcformacosx.github.io/ . However, I've deleted the ~/Library/Haskell directory where cabal was residing as well as the app directory it installs from Applicaitons. Also, ghc-mod here was built using stack and stack's build of ghc.

Comment: Paste the output to your `ghc-mod debug` please.